# Doubt in Problem 6 in Ex 8.2 in Linear Algebra by Hoffman and Kunze

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthonormal, change-of-basis

Here is the problem from Ex 8.2 in Hoffman and Kunze

[image]

Part $a$, $b$ and $c$ were trivial to solve but I am not able to solve $d$ part. The formula for part $a$ came out to be $$E(x_1,x_2) = \frac{(3x_1 + 4x_2)}{25} (3,4)$$ Now, when I try to solve $d$ part, I thought of simply assuming one basis vector to be $(x_1,x_2)$ and equating to $(1,0)$ but it turns out to be unsolvable. What am I do wrong? Can someone please help? I am reading the book on my own.

Comment: Do you know what it means for a linear transformation to be represented by a matrix?

Comment: isn't it something like u express the linear transformation as a product of two matrices where one matrix represents the unknown where u put values?

Comment: That/s not quite correct. I would suggest you read up more on this concept - it's very important in linear algebra. I'm guessing Hoffman and Kunze cover it in their text. Essentially, the idea is that a linear transformation is uniquely and totally determined by where it sends a basis. A matrix representation with respect to some basis consists of precisely this data - where each basis vector is sent. This allows for a very compact and computationally nice tool for understanding these maps.

Comment: I guess you were right. I just saw it again. I am gonna give it a try once. Thanks. Hope it works out now.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop Can you help me? I have a some other problem with $d$ now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For part d let's think about what exactly that means. We want an orthonormal basis $\{v,w\}$ such that $E$ is $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. This is the same thing as saying that $E(v)=v$ and $E(w) = 0$. Well by definition of a projection, anything in the image of $E$ satisfies $E(v)=v$. We want an orthonormal basis, so let's take this to be unit length. For instance, we can take $v=(3/5,4/5)$.

Now we need some nonzero $w$ with $E(w)=0$ and $v\perp w$. That will automatically imply that $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent, giving us our desired basis. Now, $E$ is an *orthogonal* projection, so its kernel is the orthogonal complement of its image. Thus, we need only find some unit length vector perpindicular to $(3/5,4/5)$. We can take $w=(-4/5,3/5)$.

Comment: What does this mean? "by definition of a projection, anything in the image of $E$ satisfies $E(v)=v$ " and did u choose $v = (3/5,4/5)$ randomly? Rest everything makes sense to me :) @paulblartmathcop

Comment: A projection satisfies the property $E^2=E$, so if $w=Ev$ is in the image then $Ew=E^2v=Ev=w$. If you're not familiar with projections in general, you can verify that using your formula. And $(3/5,4/5)$ was not random. $W$ is spanned by $(3,4)$ and the norm of $(3,4)$ is $5$, so I just scaled it to be a unit vector.

Comment: Do correct me if I am wrong anywhere. I think I was confused in $Ev = v$ because u had chosen $v$ to be a basis vector also. So, now what I understand is that $Ew = w$ for all $w$ in $W$. Yes, I know $E$ is idempotent, so it makes perfect sense. Also, choosing randomly I meant u have chosen any random vector which obviously belongs to $W$ and then from that vector u chose another vector $w$ due to reasons in your answer which I understood. I hope I am correct . Thanks a lot for your help. @paulblartmathcop

Comment: Also does it mean I could have chosen any vector in span of $W$ ? @paulblartmathcop

Comment: It seems like you understand fine. And the issue of if I chose randomly is mostly semantics. Given any nonzero $w \in W$, you can take $v=w/||w||$ as the first element of the basis. But then $v=(3/5,4/5)$ or $v=(-3/5,-4/5)$ (think about the intersection of the unit circle and $W$).

Comment: Oh lol u r right. We will have only two choices for first element of basis. Thanks a lot for your time and patience ^_^ . Have a good day

Comment: Glad I could help!